# Mockito: в чем разница конструкций?

Tags: java, mockito, mocking

В чем разница конструкций, и что и когда лучше применять?

```
1)   when(repository.findAll()).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);

2)   doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(repository).findAll();

3)   doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(repository.findAll());
```

Уточню: в исходники залез и быстро ответ не нашел, проверил в тесте - поведение одинаковое. Однако полной уверенности в том, что конструкции однозначные нет, поэтому и задал вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Методы `do*()` применяются для создания заглушек на `void` методы. Об этом  сказано в [документации](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12).

Вариант **#3** в таком виде, вообще говоря, у вас должен выбросить `UnfinishedStubbingException`, но общий смысл различий м/у **#2** и **#3** заключается в том, что в **#3** метод `findAll()` выполняется (вызывается реальный метод объекта), а в **#2** - нет. Вариант **#2** можно использовать, когда в методе `findAll()` присутствует сайд эффект, например, в виде изменения состояния объекта, которое вы не хотите чтобы происходило во время теста.

Можете проверить на основе простого теста (псевдо-код):

```
public class Repository {

    public int find() {
        System.out.println(42);
        return 42;
    }
}

public class RepositoryTest {

    private final Repository mock = spy(new Repository());

    // ничего не печатает
    @Test
    public void testFind1() throws Exception {
        doReturn(1).when(mock).find();
        assertTrue(mock.find() == 1);
    }

    // печатает 42
    @Test
    public void testFind2() throws Exception {
        when(mock.find()).thenReturn(1);
        assertTrue(mock.find() == 1);
    }

}
```